# ReflectionException thrown on composer update for a file that exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

To make this more interesting, things work just fine if I run `composer dump-autoload -o` but I am curious why would this throw an error when I run `composer update` in the first place? I need to get to the bottom of this. A quick fix doesn't make me happy internally.

```
aligajani at Alis-MBP in ~/Projects/saveeo on master ✗                                                                                    [faaba41c]  4:53
> composer update
> php artisan clear-compiled
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Package guzzle/guzzle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use guzzlehttp/guzzle instead.
Generating autoload files
> php artisan optimize


  [ReflectionException]                                           
  Class Saveeo\Board\Observers\BoardEventListener does not exist
```

*BoardEventListener.php* (placed in Saveeo/Board/Observers)

```
<?php

namespace Saveeo\Board\Observers;

use Saveeo\Services\HashIds\Contracts\HashIds as HashIdService;

class BoardEventListener {
    private $hashIdService;

    public function __construct(HashIdService $hashIdService) {
        $this->hashIdService = $hashIdService;
    }

    public function whenBoardIsCreated($event) {
        $this->hashIdService->syncHashIdValueOnModelChanges($event, 'board');
    }

    public function whenBoardIsUpdated($event) {
        $this->hashIdService->syncHashIdValueOnModelChanges($event, 'board');
    }

    public function subscribe($events) {
        $events->listen(
            'Saveeo\Board\Observers\Events\BoardHasBeenCreated',
            'Saveeo\Board\Observers\BoardEventListener@whenBoardIsCreated'
        );

        $events->listen(
            'Saveeo\Board\Observers\Events\BoardHasBeenUpdated',
            'Saveeo\Board\Observers\BoardEventListener@whenBoardIsUpdated'
        );

    }
}
```

*EventServiceProvider.php* (placed in Saveeo/Providers)

```
<?php

namespace Saveeo\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * The subscriber classes to register.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $subscribe = [
        'Saveeo\Board\Observers\BoardEventListener',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any other events for your application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(DispatcherContract $events) {
        parent::boot($events);

        //
    }
}
```

Here is the folder structure. Can't see anything wrong here?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ2l1.jpg

**Composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "firebase/php-jwt": "~2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "5.*",
        "guzzlehttp/oauth-subscriber": "0.2.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "2.*",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "3.*",
        "bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel": "1.*",
        "vinkla/hashids": "^2.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "~3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Saveeo\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: @Leith Please see my composer.json

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like we changed the autoloading namespace (manually, or by using `artisan app:name`) for the classes in the *app/* directory from `App` (the default) to `Saveeo` in *composer.json*:

> ```
> "autoload": {
>     "psr-4": {
>         "Saveeo\\": "app/"
>     }
> },
> ```

This is *perfectly* fine to do when we understand the implications. We can see the issue described in the question when we take a look at the project's folder structure for the file that causes the exception (with the namespaces in parentheses):

```php
app                    (Saveeo)
├── Saveeo             (Saveeo\Saveeo)
│   ├── Board          (Saveeo\Saveeo\Board)
│   │   ├── Observers  (Saveeo\Saveeo\Board\Observers)
│   │   │   ├── BoardEventListener
└── ...
```

For compatibility with PSR-4, the namespace for `BoardEventListener` should be `Saveeo\Saveeo\Board\Observers` because it exists in the *Saveeo/* directory nested under *app/*. [PSR-4 autoloading](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) implementations resolve class files based on *file names and paths*, <strike>not the namespaces declared *in* the files.</strike> [Composer *does* read the namespace from the class files to create an optimized classmap, as long as the top-level namespace matches. See update.]

If we don't want to change the directory structure of the application, and we *also* don't want to use two `Saveeo`s in the namespace, we can configure Composer to merge both directories into the same namespace when it autoloads classes:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Saveeo\\": [ "app/", "app/Saveeo/" ]
    }
},
```

...and remember to `composer dump-autoload`.

It works, but I don't recommend this in practice. It deviates from the PSR-4 standard, makes the application susceptible to namespace conflicts, and may be confusing to other people working on the project. I suggest that you flatten the `Saveeo` namespace and directory, or choose a different namespace for the classes in the nested directory.

> ...things work just fine if I run `composer dump-autoload -o` but I am curious why would this throw an error when I run `composer update`...?

When generating the autoloading cache file, Composer doesn't actually execute your code. However, the `artisan optimize` command, which runs after `composer update` in most Laravel applications (until 5.5), *does boot* the application to perform its operations, so the problem code executes and we see the exception.

**Update:**

> If using `Saveeo\Board\etc` was wrong versus doing `Saveeo\Saveeo\Board\etc` then other files around the entire application wouldn't work, but they do.

We *can* technically use non-PSR-4 namespaces that don't match the project's directory structure when we generate an *optimized* autoloader like we would to prepare an application for production:

```
composer dump-autoload --optimize
```

This works because Composer will scan each class file for namespaces to create a *static* classmap. When we don't specify `--optimize`, Composer relies on *dynamic* autoloading which matches file paths to namespaces, so non-standard namespaces or directory structures fail to resolve.

The namespacing for the project in question works for the most part, even though it doesn't follow PSR-4, because we're manually dumping an optimized autoloader by using the `-o` option for `dump-autoload`. However, we see the error message because `composer update` *removes the cached classmap* before running the update, so, by the time the `artisan optimize` command runs, the classmap no longer contains the classes that we dumped.

We can configure Composer to [always optimize the autoloader](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/autoloader-optimization.md) by setting the `optimize-autoloader` configuration directive in *composer.json*:

```
"config": { 
    "optimize-autoloader": true 
}
```

...which should fix the `install` and `update` commands for this project. It's a bit of a hack to get non-standard namespacing to resolve. With this approach, remember that we'll need to dump the autoloader whenever we add a new file in development that doesn't follow PSR-4.

Comment: This is, of course, assuming that the application namespace was actually changed from `App` using the `php artisan app:name Saveeo` command, and not just changed simply in the `composer.json`, which would do absolutely nothing without it.

Comment: @Leith Based on the service provider in the question, I'm assuming that Ali used this command or manually changed the namespace in each file. But you're right--we can't take for granted that this is true.

Comment: I used the `php artisan app:name Saveeo`. Correct. To be honest, no where else do I use `Saveeo\Saveeo`, so why would I use it in that particular file. If using `Saveeo\Board\etc` was wrong versus doing `Saveeo\Saveeo\Board\etc` then other files around the entire application wouldn't work, but they do. I will however try out this now and report back.

Comment: @CyRossignol Making the `psr-4` as you recommend, running `composer dump-autoload -o` and then `composer update` now shows a different error: `Class Saveeo\Board does not exist`? This is coming from a file called `BoardHasBeenUpdated.php` which does have the `use Saveeo\Board;` referenced correctly, as it was working before with my `psr-4` settings earlier. This is strange.

Comment: @Ali What's the namespace declared in *Board.php*? Looks like it should be `Saveeo\Board\Board` because it's in the *Board/* directory.

Comment: @CyRossignol The error is nothing coming from that class. See edits to my previous comment. Also, `Board.php` has a namespace of `namespace Saveeo;` simply that. There is something going on that we don't know about. Everything works fine. It's just one class `BoardEventListener.php` that's causing us to change things which effectively cause a chain reaction. :(

Comment: @CyRossignol Apologies. I missed the deadline and SO automatically awarded the bounty to someone else. I am not sure if we can reverse this, but I have marked your answer as the best answer. :)

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be related to the Composer PSR autoloading. By default Laravel will include

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
}
```

which means "the root of the `App` namespace is in the `app` folder, and from there match namespace to folder structure".

Your `Saveeo` namespace hasn't been registered (it's not in the `App` hierarchy), so Composer doesn't know its location.

It should work if you add another line to your composer.json (and then `dump-autoload`)

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Saveeo\\": "app/Saveeo"
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could, as the other answer points out, just place the whole `Saveeo` namespace within `App` (so it's `App\Saveeo\Board\Observers\Events\BoardHasBeenCreated` for instance). However your `Saveeo` namespace seems to be sort of a self-contained module, it may be more reasonable to have it as a separate namespace rather than renaming the namespace in all of its files.

Comment: Please see my composer.json

Comment: @AliGajani this is the correct answer, _unless_ you've used `artisan` to rename the root namspace from `App` to `Saveeo`, in which case your `app/Saveeo` folder **and** your `app/` folder would be in the `Saveeo` namespace. Alternatively if the main namespace hasn't been changed, then you _could_ change all of your namespaces as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46889828/2053165) suggests.

Comment: @AliGajani if you are matching the `Saveeo` namespace to the `app` folder, you don't need the `Saveeo` folder. Maybe the `Saveeo\Board\Observers\Events\BoardHasBeenCreated` class could just be in the `app/Board/Observers/Events/BoardHasBeenCreated.php` file.

Comment: I changed my app namespace to Saveeo from App. This is why if you see my `composer.json` I have specified that exactly in the `psr-4` block. I don't understand why this would work with `composer dump-autoload` but not the other way around. I am certain my namespacing is  fine. This is exactly why other files in the directory are found, except this. Please see my `composer.json` file again.

Answer (score 3):

I believe if you just change your namespace to:

`App\Saveeo\Board\Observers` instead of `Saveeo\Board\Observers`

all your problems should be solved. Please let me know if you have a reason for creating this new namespace, instead of just branching out from the base **App** namespace.

Comment: Why should I use the `App` namespace. `Saveoo` is just that.

Comment: Your Saveeo directory is placed under your App directory. So why create a second namespace root within an existing one? Do you see a benefit in doing that? Have you at least tried what I suggested to see if your problems will be solved this way?

Comment: That kind of namespaces is correct when you have a package under `vendor` directory, but for code inside `app` folder better to use `App` namespace, as it's the main namespace. It's a good reason for organizing code

Comment: @Lloople Please see my composer.json

Comment: I do not care about the points in the least. Won't offer me anything. I am here to help people. But when I see someone baiting for anwers with a bounty, and then so many people give him pretty much the same answer and he just dismisses it, it annoys me. And no there was no way I was getting those points. You dismissed my solution completely from the get go. Life as a developer will be rough for you with such a dismissive attitude.

Comment: And when you are not sorry for something you can simply not say you are sorry. Typing "sorry, but not sorry" is a very childish thing to do.